# auto Clicking botton through macro

Tags: vba, scripting, catia

i want to run list of macros one by one in Catia , while running every macro it displays message box . to continue next macro i am clicking ok or close button on msg box to close. until i close the message box  the next macro is not running.

i want to click ok or cancel buttons on msg box or user frame automatically through scripting or macro.so my list of Catia macros will run continuously without any manual click.

is it possible to click button through macro on user forms which are displaying

Comment: Is it an option to modify the macros so they don't show a MsgBox?

Comment: It would be advantageous to simply disable the prompts as the previous commenter suggested, but yes there is definitely a way to auto click the Ok or Cancel buttons. In the Windows operating system, for example, all buttons have a handle, HWND. You would need to have a separate concurrent program/process running though in order to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some functionality continual, wouldn't be better to just write all the functionality into the one macro and start it?

You can virtually click on buttons by SendKey function ,but based on my experience it may not be reliable.

I would recommend, and by my opinion this is the easiest way, just copy each macro to a separate classes with some static method to run it and the just call it one by one from the module with CATMain function.

Comment: thank you for your answer . Actually i am providing 2 option .one is calling commends list by list and clicking it manually. for my second option all commands has to run it self . for that reason i have to know that how to click the button automatically

Comment: @charantej Can you show an example of such a button (edit your question). Do you want for example reorder the tree?

Comment: yes, that would be appreciated

Comment: SendKey function is well described here:

https://www.scripting4v5.com/additional-articles/catia-macro-sendkeys/

But, I wouldn't recommend going that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user to choose the operating mode at the start of the macro.
Then bypass the following box messages.

```
Sub catmain()

Dim StepByStep As VbMsgBoxResult
StepByStep = MsgBox("Do you want launch Macros step by step ?", vbYesNo, "Macro mode")

.
.
.

If StepByStep = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Result MAcro 1", vbExclamation, "Result"
End If

End Sub
```